# Email verification in java

Tags: java, regex

Is there any regex to validate email which disallow `.com.com` i.e example@example.com.com but allow `.com.uk`?
I have pasted my code that should return false while user enters `.com.com`. Can anyone verify my code below?

```
String ePattern = "^[_A-Za-z0-9-\\+]+(\\.[_A-Za-z0-9-]+)*@" + "[A-Za-z0-9-]+(\\.[A-Za-z0-9]+)*(\\.[A-Za-z]{2,})$";
Pattern p =Pattern.compile(ePattern);
Matcher m = p.matcher(studentemail);
b= m.matches();
    if(!b) {
        eMsg.addError("email must be in formate: example@example.xxx / example@example.xx");
        request.setAttribute("errorMessage", eMsg);
        requestDispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher("/addrecord.jsp");
        requestDispatcher.forward(request, response);
        return;
    }   

     else {
           System.out.println("valid email id");
      }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using a regular expression to validate an email address](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/201323/using-a-regular-expression-to-validate-an-email-address)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Such a regex isn't limited to Java in most cases (only if special capabilities are used that are not supported by the Java regex engine). Besides that, if you want to match `@example.xx` only you should adjust the second part of your regex (especially the first group in that part). But note that there are domains like `xxx.co.uk` which might not be valid then.

Also `xx.com.com` *might* be an invalid domain but it also might not (at least in other combinations, e.g. `de.de` is a valid domain) so you might want to either allow that, test for specific combinations only or restrict usage of such domains.

However, depending on your use-case it would probably be better to send a confirmation email since a regex can just tell you that it *looks* correct but there might still be errors.